# How to convert RAW data sets into standardize dataset

Tags: python-2.7, data-science

[image][image: how to convert these datasets into valid datasets ,to do further case study]

I have copied these datasets and now i want to make these data sets in standardize form,i am a beginner wit respect to data science,so how i can do further by using python code

is_mobile,n_products_viewed,visit_duration,is_returning_visitor,time_of_day,user_action
     1,0,0.657509946,0,3,0
     1,1,0.568571234,0,2,1
     1,0,0.042245997,1,1,0
     1,1,1.659793381,1,1,2
     0,1,2.014744849,1,1,2
     1,1,0.512447387,1,1,2
     0,0,1.440327098,1,1,0
     1,0,0.035260233,0,3,0
     0,1,1.490764094,0,0,1
      0,0,0.005837521,1,3,0
      0,4,2.04604049,1,0,3
     0,0,0.955889466,0,3,0

Comment: it would be better if you have posted your RAW dataset and expected dataset ... in TEXT form

Comment: is that ok sir.n expected is in a row and column wise it should get set

Comment: also post the *standardize form*

Comment: sir,my data set is comma seperated one,what i wanted is to remove commas,and then that single data should aquire a single row and single column,rest should follow for all data.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking to tidy your data. below are general concession with definition of tidy data.

```
Each variable you measure should be in one column.
Each different observation of that variable should be in a different row.
There should be one table for each "kind" of variable.
If you have multiple tables, they should include a column in the table that allows them to be linked.
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data

I donot see any issue with having comma as delimiter. pandas can load csv with pandas.read_csv().

if you would like to do some clearing and rearranging of data you can use pivot_table and melt methods from pandas library.